# Assign Custom post to Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called 'product_type' and a a custom post called 'product'. I have a cron job that is pulling in data from an external system and adds products as custom posts using `insert_post($post)`. This returns the post id. I now need to assign the product to the 'DVD' product_type in the taxonomy.
I have tried `wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, 'dvd', 'product_type' )` but I dont know what goes in the object_id variable, post_id doesnt work.

Can anyone help please?
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$object_id is supposed to be a post's ID, make sure first that $post->ID would even output an ID, if not, the problem lies there.